# .bak file from MYSQL to MS SQL SERVER

Tags: mysql, restore, sql-server-2019

I have got a .bak file of mysql database created using Linked server concept, the MYSQL Database has been accessed through SQLServer Instance. I wanted to import that to SQLSERVER 2019 database.

Is it same as a normal restore process or Is there anything I have to be careful about?

Comment: MySql has no concept of "backup", therefore it has no mysql .bak file.

Comment: Using Linked server concept, the MYSQL Database has been accessed through SQLServer Instance. Need to Restore the backup of this database to a new SQL server instance.

Comment: Even then, there is no "backup" in MySql. Though linked servers you can do direct queries, but that's it. If you want to copy data, you need to create a similar structure in the MSSQL server, then do an `INSERT ....... SELECT FROM mysql.........` type of query, for each table. You'll still need to rewrite every single view, stored procedure, trigger, etc..